# Valid CSS or Hack?

Tags: css

Putting this at the top of your CSS file:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

hack? or valid CSS? What does it do? and how portable to different browsers/versions?

Comment: I think you mean kludge in this instance, not hack.  Yes, I know I'm pedantic.

Comment: I guess what I consider a hack is when certain browser actually choke on a certain character or set of characters and other browsers don't. But I guess from the responses the * is a valid character for "wildcard".... so I would think this is not a hack.

Comment: Since the * selector was introduced specifically to affect all elements, it is not a hack IMO. However, using it at the top of your CSS with the intention of avoiding cross browser issues might be considered a tool in the toolbox of 'CSS hacking', which has a more loose definition than 'hacking' per se

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is valid CSS.  It selects EVERY element and resets the default margins and paddings.  The reason people use this is to make their site layout more consistent across different browsers/versions, as each browser has its own default stylesheet.  If you don't use this declaration or specify a margin/padding for each element, each browser will use its own default margins/paddings for that element and the page will be rendered inconsistently across different browsers.

Comment: A very articulate  and accurate description IMHO. My favorite example of where this is useful is a table with a few rows an a few columns and no other style tags. View it in IE and FF and see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/

This is part of the “CSS Reset” theory.This eliminates all differences in padding and margin across browsers Its very heavy on the rendering agent to apply rules to every single element in the document, especially with large web pages, and this can also destroy a lot of good default styling, especially when you want to have default styled submit buttons.

Comment: I honestly don't know. My best guess is that people think the 'reset' *should* work without a significant increase in workload. If the rendering engines were well designed. The engine *should* apply a rule to every element - if not, how can it render?

Comment: I used to use this method all the time but stopped doing it after a while because I hated having to reset all the margins and padding on lists, paragraphs and headings etc. Now I prefer to leave them set as defaults because the defaults are not that bad despite being slightly different across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The star is known as the [universal selector](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=358552), and is valid CSS. All it does it apply the styles to *all* elements in the page. It should be used carefully, however. Personally, I haven't found great use for it. Resetting the margins and paddings of all elements is something you can do more specifically (and in my opinion better) with other elements, element groups, and classes.

See [this page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006a.html) for details on browser support. (Note that it is seriously out of date, having been written in 2000; I would imagine you could expect full support in all popular browsers nowadays.)

> The universal selector is supported in
>   Internet Explorer 5.x for both Windows
>   and Macintosh, as well as IE 4.5 for
>   Mac, and also in Opera 3.6. It's also
>   supported in the Netscape 6 Preview
>   Release 1 on all the myriad platforms
>   for which it's available, and in
>   Preview Release 3 of Opera 4 for
>   Windows.

Comment: 'preview release 3 of Opera 4' - seriously out of date, indeed! (but we can ssume that current versions of the browsers mentioned still support it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is:

- Valid CSS
- Not really a "hack"
- A bit of a kludge
- Probably not what you want anyway

`*` is the universal selector. In the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity), the universal selector has a specificity of 0000, which means that every other selector has higher precedence. Thus, this is a way to "reset" all the margins in a way that any other rule would be able to override.

Keep in mind that this approach would render your lists a mess. Without margins and padding, the list items are no longer indented. Some rules really are beneficial in that they style things that normally aren't considered as needing styling.

The universal selector selects every single element on the page. Every little `div`, every little `li`, and so on. In fact, it even selects things that are not block-level elements, like `a` and `span` and `head`. In many cases, this is overkill, and it can be quite inefficient on large pages.

If you're looking for a way to reset the default styling on HTML, you're better off using something like Eric Meyer's [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). While the Reset CSS stylesheet is much more complex, it doesn't go overboard with selecting every single element. Otherwise, just zero out the margin and padding of each individual element that's bothering you. (I always zero out the padding and margin of `body` and `h1` as soon as I start on a page.)

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes see:

```
html * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

or

```
body * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

which have slightly different results in various browsers. Just something to be aware of.

Also, there are selective resets that don't include every HTML element - see this article [comparing kinds of CSS reset](http://www.kennycarlile.net/2008/06/19/yahoo-vs-eric-meyer-css-reset/).

It can't be a hack, because it is valid and standard CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid CSS, but technically it could be considered a hack.

Basically it's used to reset the margins and padding on every element in the HTML because different browsers sometimes have different defaults.  Using this reset will ensure that all elements start from a common point.

Answer (score 0):

It's both valid and a hack.  However, it's not a browser specific one.  The term for it is "css reset"

As tf111 explained, the idea is to get rid of the browser specific settings for margin and padding that are different across all browsers

Comment: I guess in my thinking its not a hack. A trick maybe. See comments at root question level.

Comment: Given your comment, I can definitely see where you are coming from.  I was using the term hack pretty loosely.